# unable to get updated scope value after ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I tried the below code. I have searched for answers for answer and solutions to use $apply, $timeout but anything didn't work in my case. I am getting bunch errors.

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("test",[])
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
         controller: 'loginCtrl'
    })
 });

app.controller("loginCtrl",["$scope","$http","$location",function($scope,$http,$sessionStorage,$location,$timeout) {
    $scope.loginSuccess = false;
    $scope.loginAuthencation = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'post',
            url:'http://192.168.42.200:5000/authenticate',
            data:{"username":$scope.username,"password":$scope.password}
        }).then(function successCallback(successResponse) {
            console.log(successResponse);
            if(successResponse.data.status==="success"){                                    
                $scope.loginSuccess = true; 
            } else {
                $scope.loginSuccess = false;
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.loginSuccess = false;
        });
    }
}]);
```

**index.html :**

```
<p>{{loginSuccess}}</p>
<div ng-view></div>
```

**login.html:**

```
<div>
    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="appicon"/>
</div>
<div class="sub-element">
    <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" ng-model="username"/></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" ng-model="password"/></p>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" value="Remember Me" class="item-left"/>Remember Me
<p class="submit-btn"><input type="submit" id="login-form" value="Login" ng-click="loginAuthencation()" /></p>
```

value is not getting updated...

Comment: what is an error??

Comment: as per the above code..No errors but the value is not getting updated to true after ajax success

Comment: can you share your json response structure as well ? In your success function check console.log(successResponse)

Comment: {{loginSuccess} gives value false ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `<p>{{loginSuccess}}</p>` outside your ng-view. Therefore loginCtrl's scope won't be accessible. Either access `<p>{{loginSuccess}}</p>` inside login.html or use `$rootScope.loginSuccess` so that it works everywhere.

Comment: see my updated question sorry for confusion. I have used the same way.

Comment: ok. what does console.log(successResponse); print in the browser console?

Comment: can you try if(successResponse.data.status=="success"){  with double == instead of ===

Comment: umm. Can you tell me what console.log(successResponse.data.status) prints and put a console inside your if condition and check if it enters inside.

Comment: Now I got the issue..view part was dynamically loaded using routeprovidedr and the function was called from there. so it was not working I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112604/discussion-between-nikhilesh-k-v-and-susheel-singh).

Answer (score -1):

Can you try below one :

```
    function(successResponse) {   
                if(successResponse.data.status==="success"){                                        
                    $scope.loginSuccess = true;     
                } else {
                    $scope.loginSuccess = false;
                }
              if(!$scope.$$phase) {
               $scope.$digest();
}

            }
```

Comment: You can check if a $digest is already in progress by checking $scope.$$phase.

Comment: $scope.$digest() will simply sync its model to the view, but will not digest its parents scope, which can save a lot of performances when working on an isolated part of your HTML with an isolated scope (from a directive mostly). $digest does not take a callback: you execute the code, then digest.

Comment: $scope.$digest(); is not required here as after $http success callback it automatically gets triggered.

Comment: Please refer this doc http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angularjs-watch-digest-and-apply-oh-my.html  It has mentioned as DO use $digest/$apply in directives to let Angular know you've made changes after an asynchronous call, such as a DOM event.
DO use $digest/$apply in services to let Angular know some asynchronous operation has returned, such as a WebSocket update, or an event from a 3rd party library like Facebook API.

Comment: @TanviB nikhilesh is correct. $digest is not required. It was some other issue due to routerprovider, which I figured out just now. anyways thanks for your inputs

Comment: @TanviB in the same link check out "When you update the model in the scope via some in-framework call... $http.get() for example, it kicks off a $digest after it completes." . A digest is required when you do things outside the angular implementation. For example you trigger $.ajax instead of $http then you need to manually call digest.